# Recursion error calling a function using a post-save signal

Tags: django, python-3.x, recursion, django-signals

I have a Category model, where the ForeignKey is to self.

```
class Category(SEO, MetaData):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), blank=True, null=True)
```

I introduced the path field, to avoid recursion in widget, and do it model, because is not often done.

I use a post_save signal to ssave the path:

```
def _recurse_for_parent(cat_obj, path=None):
    # path at the beginning don't exist and need to be initialized
    if not path:
        path = []
    if cat_obj.parent is not None:
        _recurse_for_parent(cat_obj.parent, path)
    return path


def save_path(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.parent_id:
        instance.children = _recurse_for_parent(instance.parent)
        instance.save()



post_save.connect(save_path, sender=Category)
```

My issue is that I get the "maximum recursion depth error" and I don't see why, because I use the condition:

```
cat_obj.parent is not None:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error in `def save_path` I call `instance.save()`, which will trigger the `post_save` signal.

Because `post_save` signal calls `save_path` and `save path` calls `save` which trigger `post_save`, I'm entering in an infinite loop.

I solved by moving my logic to the `save` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in the function

```
def _recurse_for_parent(cat_obj, path=None):
    # path at the beginning don't exist and need to be initialized
    if not path:
        path = []
    if cat_obj.parent is not None:
        _recurse_for_parent(cat_obj.parent, path)
    return path
```

First have in mind that `not []` will return True, so if you set path to [] the function will do the same thing every time. Use `is None` instead

Second the value from the recursive call is never used.

Finally think of what will append when both condition are True.